# How can I load multiple textures in Opengl es 2.x (in android with libgdx)

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, libgdx

```
Gdx.gl20.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0);
texture.bind();
```

I am able to bind 1 texture like this... But if I cant figure out how to bind more textures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE1) and bind.

[tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/ShaderMultitextureTest.java](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/ShaderMultitextureTest.java)

```
Gdx.gl20.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE1);
texture2.bind();
```